# Why did Ubuntu change from "Gnome-desktop" to "Unity"?

Tags: desktop-environments

What was so bad about gnome and what was so good about unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Founded in 2010, the Unity project started by Mark Shuttleworth and
>   Canonical has gone on to deliver a consistent user experience for
>   desktop and netbook users alike. Putting great design at the heart of
>   the project, Unity and its technologies such as Application
>   indicators, System indicators, and Notify OSD, have strived to solve
>   common problems in the Free Software desktop while optimizing the
>   experience for touch, consistency and collaboration.

**Courtesy:** http://unity.ubuntu.com/about/

As to the reason for the splitup:

> Canonical made the switch for the next release of its Ubuntu desktop
>   Linux distribution, because of increasingly divergent views of how a
>   desktop interface should look and operate, according to Canonical
>   founder Mark Shuttleworth.

You can read in detail at:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/208708/article.html

Answer (score 0):

They changed to Unity to make it more touch friendly.They decided to make the whole interface touch friendly because of the increasing use of ubuntu on mobile platforms and as Tv interfaces and for other devices .

Comment: Do you have a source for that?  This seems separate to the usual reasons given, such as the need to adapt to small screens (hence why it debuted first in the Netbook Remix project) and disagreements with Gnome over UI.

Comment: @neon_overload: I heard this reason in keynote adress of Mark Shuttleworth at at UDS, BTW main reason is to get unified interface in pc ,tablet, mobile and other ubuntu devices